# Getting Laravel S3 issue Filename Cannot be Empty on Live website

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, file-upload, runtime-error

**Hello Folks,** I hope you guys are well.

Last week I am getting an issue in my **Laravel Application** which is regarding the **S3 bucket**.

**Files**, **Images** and **PDF** are not getting store in my S3 Bucket. The code which I have written is working fine for me for last 10 months in production environment.

Then I checked that code in my **local machine** which is **(localhost)** and that is working fine. Then I clear my **Laravel** Application its **Cache , Views , Routes , Config**. Also, checked my **.env** file which is same as local environment.

The last thing which I can do is check the **incognito mode** after clearing all the cache routes and other things. In incognito mode my files are getting uploaded for the production site but when I upload that image from the normal window its showing me the get file content error.

I am giving you the screenshots and the code which I am using let me know if you can help me with this and yes I know the problem is very strange.

> **My Controller Function**

```
public function saveAboutBannerSlide(Request $request){
        $banner_tile = $request->banner_title;
        $banner_des = $request->banner_des;

        //Getting File name form the form
        $file = $request->file('banner_image');

        //S3 OBJECT
        $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
        $new = uniqid() . "_banner";

        //Uploading With the New Name
        $upload_path = 'uploads/manage-cms/aboutus-images/' . $new;

        //Put File in S3 Bucket
        $s3->put($upload_path, file_get_contents($file));

        //Getting URL OF THE Image
        $up_img = $s3->url($upload_path);

}
```

> **Error image while uploading image**

[image: Error while uploading image please have a look]

Comment: If you guys need anything in terms of files or code etc. I will share that as well but before going to say something the code is working fine in my localhost machine.

Comment: anyone can help me with this?